# Display html with ajax using Rails embedded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, link-to

I am new at Rails and saw that it has some embedded ajax. I am trying to use is it to display my chat. However, it is not working and I am not receiving any message of error also.

I have a DIV in my index where I want to show the result of the call. It gets all the messages and uses the html to deploy it.

My index page (with the link)

```rb
<%= link_to url: get_messages_from_user_path(user_to: user_to_id), class: 'get_messages_from', remote: true do %>
                        <div class="chat_list">
                            <div class="chat_people">
                                <div class="chat_img"> <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"> </div>
                                <div class="chat_ib">
                                    <h5> <%= user_to_name %> <span class="chat_date">Dec 25</span></h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    <% end %>
```

My routes

```rb
get 'messages', to: 'messages#get_messages_from_user', as: 'get_messages_from_user'
```

My controller

```rb
def get_messages_from_user
        @messages = Messages.all
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.js 
        end
    end
```

My js file:

named: get_messages_from_user.js.erb

```
$("#messages_ajax").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'messages/get_messages_from_user', locals: { messages: @messages } ) %>");
```

My html file:
named: _get_messages_from_user.html.erb

I want to print everything from here

Please, let me know anything else that is missing in my question.

Comment: `$("#messages_ajax")` Is using jQuery to locate the element with id `messages_ajax`. Where is the element located on your index? I dont see it

Comment: Do you want to get messages in one browser tab if you send other messages in another browser tab?

Comment: @Jeff That code is over the index page, the same page as the link_to is localized... I did not understand your question Andriy